# Turtle and drawing tree with RapydScript

Tags: python, browser, turtle-graphics, rapydscript

today I want draw a tree in browser with RapydScript.
I have code in Python:

```
import random
import turtle

def tree(size, myTurtle):
    myTurtle.pensize(size / 20)

    if size < random.randint(1,2) * 20:
        myTurtle.color("green")
    else:
        myTurtle.color("brown")

    if size > 5:
        myTurtle.forward(size)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.right(50)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        myTurtle.penup()
        myTurtle.backward(size)
        myTurtle.pendown()

window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(800,600)
window.bgcolor("white")

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.color("brown", "blue")
myTurtle.left(90)
myTurtle.speed(0)
myTurtle.penup()
myTurtle.setpos(0, -250)
myTurtle.pendown()
```

And I want to run it in browser to get this effect:

[image]
​Don't worry about text over the tree, is in polish ;) I run this in Skulpt, maybe you hear about it, effect you have above.
Now I want to run this in RapydScript and compare it to Skulpt and Brython.

I am wonder if it possible in RapydScript beacuse this code use turtle module.
I guess that I need to change this code somehow to run it on RapydScript. 
Did RapydScript allow to import turtle module?

As you can see here:
http://www.transcrypt.org/live/turtle_site/turtle_site.html

Transcrypt(similiar tool to RapydScript) somehow can draw with turtle.

Can you help me with this?

Of course I want use Python, I know that RapydScript allows to use JavaScript, but I want Python :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `src/lib` in [RapydScript repo](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript) - there is no `turtle` module. And it can't import turtle module from Python because it doesn't draw on canvas in browser. So you can't draw tree if you doesn't create turtle module.

Answer (score 2):

As @furas mentioned, there is no `turtle` module in the base repo. First of all, I think you're misunderstanding what the `turtle` module is, it's nothing more than an abstraction around another graphics library. Even in Python, it's not the preferred way of handling graphics, it's just a subset of Logo toolkit aimed at making programming easier to kids.

With that said, Transcrypt exists in the exact same JavaScript world as RapydScript, the `turtle` it uses has nothing to do with Python's `turtle`, it's a wrapper around SVG. In fact, here it is: [https://github.com/JdeH/Transcrypt/blob/master/transcrypt/modules/turtle/**init**.py](https://github.com/JdeH/Transcrypt/blob/master/transcrypt/modules/turtle/__init__.py)

And looking at that code, I can tell you that you can copy-paste it almost verbatim into RapydScript to "gain" a turtle module there. Everything that code does is supported by RapydScript, even the import mechanism between RS and Transcrypt will work the same.

Moreover, a quick Google search revealed 2 JavaScript implementations of this `turtle` module (which you can just attach to the same page as RapydScript and use them as if they're Python):
http://berniepope.id.au/html/js-turtle/turtle.html
https://github.com/davebalmer/turtlewax

Finally, whether or not you use the `turtle` module doesn't make your code any more or less Python. You also seem to have a misconception that by using a JavaScript library from RapydScript, you need to write the rest of the code in JavaScript. That is not the case, The RapydScript examples directory already shows [D3](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript/tree/master/examples/d3_treemap), [canvas](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript/tree/master/examples/paint), and [WebGL](http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/RotatingCubes-RapydScript/edit) examples. The reason there is no turtle module is because it's obsolete compared to the graphics libraries that JavaScript (and RapydScript) has access to. You're welcome to do a pull request with a turtle module implementation, however.